# How to get the images links from a page with slides

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Can I use scrapy to get all the images links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Open HTML (source code) and you see

```
imgAr1[0] = "slides/01.jpg";
imgAr1[1] = "slides/los-altos-remodel.jpg";
imgAr1[2] = "slides/los-altos-remodeling.jpg";
imgAr1[3] = "slides/los-altos-home-remodeling.jpg";
imgAr1[4] = "slides/home-remodel-los-altos.jpg";
imgAr1[5] = "slides/remodel-los-altos.jpg";
imgAr1[6] = "slides/los-altos-remodeling-contractors.jpg";
imgAr1[7] = "slides/remodeling-los-altos.jpg";
imgAr1[8] = "slides/los-altos-home-remodel.jpg";
imgAr1[9] = "slides/home-remodeling-los-altos.jpg";
```

Use regular expression and you get all links to all images.